# Chef Template If Attribute Exists

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

I've got an optional attribute on my nodes. I want my template to only set a specific value if that attribute exists:

```
<% if node['haproxy']['server']['backup'] %>
server <%= node['haproxy']['server']['backup']['hostname'] %> <%= node['haproxy']['server']['backup']['ipaddress'] %>:<%= node['mysql']['port'] %> weight 1 maxconn 100 check
<% end %>
```

This looks good to me but when I run it I'm getting the following error:

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
------------------------------------
no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

**How can I get this working so Chef recognizes if the attribute is set?**

Comment: Turns out I needed to use an object instead of an array.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<% if node['haproxy']['server'].attribute?('backup') %>
```